# How to find who deleted clearCase Trigger?

Tags: clearcase, ibm-rational

In some of the vobs ClearCase triggers got deleted, don't see anything in the log too. Is there a way to find who did this ?

Comment: Sorry for the belated answer: I completely missed your last ClearCase question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way [ClearCase events are recorded](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21239928)

> **Running `lshistory` on the VOB object will show deletion events**.
>   This provides at least a history of who removed a type, and when, along with any comments that were entered at removal.
>   Without storing these events in the VOB object, there would be no record of by who and when objects were removed.

Example:

```
The creation event is visible in the history.

% cleartool lshistory -long brtype:NEWBR
15-Oct-03.16:32:41     John Doe (jdoe.clearuser@host1)
 create branch type "NEWBR"

Once removed, the type object's removal event is only visible in the history.

% cleartool rmtype -rmall brtype:NEWBR
Removed branch type "NEWBR".

% cleartool lshistory -long vob:<tag>
15-Oct-03.16:32:41     John Doe (jdoe.clearuser@host1)
 destroy type in versioned object base "<tag>"
 "Destroyed branch type "NEWBR"."
```

In your case, look for a deletion message similar to:

```
"Destroyed trigger type "XXX"."
```

See more with [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&rs=984&uid=swg21245108):

#### Windows Example:

```
M:\dynamic_view\test_vob>cleartool lshistory -all | findstr /C:"Destroyed trigger type"
  "Destroyed trigger type "VERSION"."
```

Note: The `findstr` command is used with the `/C` option in this example.
There is a colon with no space preceding `/C` indicating that everything in the quotes should be searched for as a single item.

#### UNIX/Linux Example:

```
%>cleartool lshistory -all | grep 'Destroyed trigger type'
  "Destroyed trigger type "VERSION"."
```